# Implicit array size in C++11 similar to C arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

In C++ you can say the following:

```
int xs[] = { 1, 2 };
```

Here the size of the array can be inferred at compile time to be two, so there is no need to explicitly say:

```
int xs[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

Is there an equivalent to the first construct using C++11 arrays - a way to define one without explicitly specifying the size? Maybe something like this:

```
array<int, _> xs = { 1, 2 };  // does not compile
```

rather than having to specify:

```
array<int, 2> xs = { 1, 2 };
```